# beanstalkd: unknown flag: -d

Tags: ubuntu, beanstalkd

I have installed beanstalkd using

```
sudo apt-get install beanstalkd
```

which installed beanstalkd version 1.7

now to start the beanstalkd process I am using the command

```
sudo beanstalkd -d -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300 -z 1000000
```

I am getting a response

```
beanstalkd: unknown flag: -d
Use: beanstalkd [OPTIONS]

Options:
 -b DIR   wal directory
 -f MS    fsync at most once every MS milliseconds (use -f0 for "always fsync")
 -F       never fsync (default)
 -l ADDR  listen on address (default is 0.0.0.0)
 -p PORT  listen on port (default is 11300)
 -u USER  become user and group
 -z BYTES set the maximum job size in bytes (default is 65535)
 -s BYTES set the size of each wal file (default is 10485760)
            (will be rounded up to a multiple of 512 bytes)
 -c       compact the binlog (default)
 -n       do not compact the binlog
 -v       show version information
 -V       increase verbosity
 -h       show this help
```

Answer (score 2):

`-d` was for 'daemonise'ing Beanstalkd into the background, but that has been depreciated, and now removed.

There are some samples in [the BeanstalkD git repo](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd/tree/master/adm) for using common system tools to run it as a service.  On Ubuntu, you would likely use the 'Upstart' system, for example.